# jquery function with Ajax failing in Chrome and Opera

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization

I'm having difficulty with this one function.  It works fine in IE and in Firefox, but it fails in Opera and Chrome.

basically I want to validate a form and then serialize the post variables.  I then send it to a php page that inserts a record in a database.

From there, I change the html in the original div with html code that is sent back from the php page.

Why would this be working in some browsers and not others?  Here is my code:

```
$("#newteamsubmit").live('click', function() {

    valid = $("#tcreate").valid();
                if(valid){

    var teamform = document.forms["createteam"];

var dataString = $(teamform).serialize();

   $('#entryprocess').html('<p align="center"><img src="loader.gif" /></p>').show();            

    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'joinprocess/entryform.php',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data){            
        $('#entryprocess').html($('#joinform' , data).html()).fadeIn;       


    }
    })
                }

    $('#enterhlm').validate();
    });
```

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated

Comment: is there any error in chrome console?

Comment: i think u left out some field ..is valid a required field or checks digit only of sm ting like that??

Comment: no error in the console.  Instead of re-populating the html of the div #entryprocess, it simply reverts back to the html originally loaded with the page.  IE and firefox load the new html.  I know that the data is being sent to the server because the database is being updated....Thanks for helping.  I'm still new to Jquery and I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I needed to prevent the default behaviour of the button.  Thanks to those who made suggestions